# Fatal error: Call to undefined function iconv_substr() in /home/foodpack/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/String.php on line 103

Tags: java, php, html, css, magento

Hi all anyone knows what cousing this type of error?
Fatal error: Call to undefined function iconv_substr() in /home/foodpack/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/String.php on line 103
page

```
return iconv_substr($string, $offset, $length, self::ICONV_CHARSET);
```

; This file is for CGI/FastCGI installations.
; Try copying it to php5.ini, if it doesn't work

; adjust memory limit

memory_limit = 1024M

max_execution_time = 18000

; disable magic quotes for php request vars

magic_quotes_gpc = off

; disable automatic session start
; before autoload was initialized

flag session.auto_start = off

; enable resulting html compression

zlib.output_compression = on

; disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

suhosin.session.cryptua = off

; turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

zend.ze1_compatibility_mode = off

; PHP for some reason ignores this setting in system php.ini 
; and disables mcrypt if this line is missing in local php.ini

extension=mcrypt.so

; Disable PHP errors, notices and warnings output in production mode to prevent exposing sensitive information.

display_errors = Off
this is my php.ini

Comment: update you question and add the related  code

Comment: return iconv_substr($string, $offset, $length, self::ICONV_CHARSET);

Comment: which php version you are using ?

Comment: install iconv extension on server fixed the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check in you php.ini  and (eventually) uncomment

```
extension=iconv.so
```

if you have this entry

```
[iconv]
;iconv.input_encoding = ISO-8859-1
;iconv.internal_encoding = ISO-8859-1
;iconv.output_encoding = ISO-8859-1
```

Uncomment remove the initial ;

Comment: what i actually w=have to do with this?

Comment: open your  php.ini and check if there is an entry (commented) for the extension .. then if there is extensione  commented  you must uncomment, save the modified php.ini file and (could be you need) restart you web server .. (make a copy before change the php.ini)

Comment: hi thanks for your help but i can't see any extension=iconv.so
 in php.ini

Comment: which version of php you are using ? .. (run phpinfo  for check version and extension enabled)

Comment: I have update the answer  adding a sample for php 5.4

Comment: Current PHP version: 5.6.30

Comment: i have already update the answer  .. take a look . ( and remember the backup copy before change the file)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But now i have more trouble as after this page won't show footer and some of the products '://

Comment: Many thanks  ... comment  me the link  .. of your new question .. if i cant  i take a look ..